# Magento 1.9.4 using PHP 7.3.5

Tags: magento-1.9, php-7

Can Magento 1.9.4 run using PHP 7.3.5?

I have seen a number of Stack Exchange posts to the contrary and some supporting it.

I have PHP 7.3.5 installed on the server but how (if possible) do I tell Magento to use the latest version?

Kevin

Comment: depends on your web stack configuration, what you have inatalled?

Answer (score 2):

Was there ever a solution to this? gets a lot of traffic would be good to know a lot of M1 users coming up to issues pertaining to this now.

Like me as well. Currently running 1.9.4.4 perfectly fine on 7.2, but server moving to 7.3 and want to make sure it will still be ok!

By the way, i had to post an answer because i do not have enough reputation to comment

Answer (score 1):

I have checked and found something for you:

You can check the details report about PHP version support by Magento 1 here.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html#ce19-1941

So, As I have reviewed the doc it will support php7.2.

You can check the future information here.

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/ce19-ee114/ce1.9_release-notes.html

Comment: Thanks for the info - any idea how to force Magento to use PHP 7.2, or is it a Server issue?

Comment: your server have php 7.3? which server/hosting you are using?

Comment: CentOS - yes, 7.3.2

Comment: Is your server is dadicated?

Comment: Not Dedicated, VPS - with SSH access

Comment: Then you should talk with server support. then will change it to 7.2 and there should be setting in control pannel for that.